# Error in Connecting kinesis as the target using dms

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, aws-dms

I am trying pass data aws s3-DMS-kinesis. I have uploaded a cab file in s3 bucket. I have successfully retrieved the data from s3 using DMS but when I am trying to connect the DMS target to kinesis, I am getting error “ failed to connect to database”. When I tried in my personal account it is successful but when I tried to do it using my professional account, I got that error. Could anyone tell me what should I do to solve this error?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the VPC configuration is setup on your personal account but you will have to enable Kinesis to allow inbound traffic from AWS DMS. You can do this by adding the private IP address of the DMS replication task in the Kinesis security group's Inbound rule.